# a way to disable Monolog on a per-script basis?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

we have some rather large data-import scripts (Symfony "Commands") which are erroring out due to Monolog running out of memory (vendor\monolog\src\Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter.php on line 58).  we use Monolog in general, so would not like to disable it entirely.

Comment: Do you run your scripts in prod environment (--env=prod)? 'cause this way monolog shouldn't log anything until given log level is reached (usually ERROR).

Comment: that does help - the import script gets through another couple thousand records - however it eventually errors out again.  curiously, it errors out in another location (vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 418). I had this error before, which I fixed with batch processing (a la http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html). I have tried making my batches smaller, however disabling monolog entirely is still the only thing that seems to fix these errors (--env=prod or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realise this is an old question, but when I ran into problems with a long-running, Monolog-using script generating out of memory errors, it turned out the problem was Monolog's 'fingers_crossed' handler buffering a ton of log messages.

I solved the problem by setting the 'buffer_size' variable for the Monolog handler in question. Something like this:

```
main:
    type:         fingers_crossed
    action_level: info
    buffer_size:  200
    handler:      nested
```

Edit: As pointed out by Sergio in the comments, `buffer_size` sets: 'How many entries should be buffered at most, beyond that the oldest items are removed from the buffer'.

Comment: Improving your asnwer:
buffer_size : How many entries should be buffered at most, beyond that the oldest items are removed from the buffer.
source: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/BufferHandler.php

Answer (score 1):

Since in prod environment you have problems with Doctrine I don't think focusing on logger will improve your situation. However, you could try popping log handlers off the stack with multiple calls to `$logger->popHandler()`. Might be that log messages are stacked and therefore you run out of memory.

More likely you have issues with doctrine though.

I'd try using XHProf or XDebug to see where's the actual issue. Just because your script fails at one point doesn't mean it's the cause of the problem (actual memory leak might be somewhere else).